# iframe doesn't show up from Rich Text Editor in Sitecore

Tags: jquery, html, sitecore

I am trying to add an iframe into my RTE field in Sitecore and when it renders the page, the iframe disappears. I am not sure what to do here. I went here http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/sitecore_rich_text_field_iframe_gotcha/ 
but wrapping it only made the xsl show up and not the iframe inside. Also I can't set my HtmlEditor.SupportWebControls to false as there are buttons and custom content that is added to the RTE field. Its a simple iframe in a div:

```
<div id="container">
   <iframe src="http://www.google.com/sourcehere.html></frame>
</div>
```

All that shows up on the page is:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: How are you rendering the field?

Comment: just calling the RTE, so all the HTML is inside that RTE, simple FieldRenderer

Comment: Note in the question is a </frame> instead of <iframe>

Answer (score 1):

I have used iframe in the RTE and it is displayed without any issue. The code is as follows:

**On the Sublayout (ASCX):**

- Register the Tag Prefix as follows:

  `<%@ Register Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" TagPrefix="sc" %>`
- Add the rendering field as follows:

  `<sc:Text ID="ScBody" runat="server"/>`

**In the CodeBehind (ASCX.CS):**

- Add this to the Page_Load

  `this.ScBody.Field = FieldIDs.Body.ToString();`
- or you may use the Context Item as follows:

  `this.ScBody.Field = Sitecore.Context.Item.Value(FieldIDs.Body);`

***Note that FieldIDs.Body is the Field Id of my RTE***